# Is it OK to use unique, stable functions (e.g. components) rather than strings as React keys?

Tags: reactjs

When answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564250/is-it-possible-to-get-the-name-of-a-nested-inner-react-component-by-calling-a-f/54565769#54565769) I ended up using an index as a key in the following code:

```
const menuItems = [
  { Page: ActiveDeals, Icon: Home },
  { Page: UpcomingDates, Icon: CalendarToday },
  { Page: DealsPipeline, Icon: FilterList }
];
const mappedMenuItems = menuItems.map((menuItem, index) => (
  <DashboardListItem
    key={index}
    {...menuItem}
    ShownPage={this.state.shownPage}
    setShownPage={this.setShownPage}
  />
));
```

This was fine in this case since the order isn't volatile, but ideally I would have used something specific to the data for the unique key. In this case, I didn't have (or need) any string identifiers in the data. The main unique thing about each entry in this array was the content component passed via the `Page` property to each `menuItem`. This function would be unique to each menu item and would be stable over time (not change with re-renders) so it fits most of the criteria for the `key` property when rendering a list/array of components, but the documentation indicates strings as the preferred key type.

So I wondered, "Is it OK to use a function as a key?"

I've included my own answer at the same time as posting the question, but feel free to answer as well if you have something to add -- particularly if you know of specific reasons for why the React team recommends strings as keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question I first looked in the docs which definitely strongly suggest that keys be strings.

From https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component

> A “key” is a special **string** attribute you need to include when
>   creating lists of elements.

and also in https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

> The best way to pick a key is to use a string that uniquely identifies
>   a list item among its siblings. When you don’t have stable IDs for
>   rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort

So far the docs mention strings and integers (e.g. index), but I still wondered whether there was any harm in using something else. So the next place to look was the source code.

To find the correct source code, I left off a key where I should have one and then used the resulting message ("Each child in a list should have a unique...") to search the GitHub repository. This brought me to [ReactChildFiber.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactChildFiber.js). I then found the following function relevant to my question:

```
  function mapRemainingChildren(
    returnFiber: Fiber,
    currentFirstChild: Fiber,
  ): Map<string | number, Fiber> {
    // Add the remaining children to a temporary map so that we can find them by
    // keys quickly. Implicit (null) keys get added to this set with their index
    // instead.
    const existingChildren: Map<string | number, Fiber> = new Map();

    let existingChild = currentFirstChild;
    while (existingChild !== null) {
      if (existingChild.key !== null) {
        existingChildren.set(existingChild.key, existingChild);
      } else {
        existingChildren.set(existingChild.index, existingChild);
      }
      existingChild = existingChild.sibling;
    }
    return existingChildren;
  }
```

So here `existingChildren` is a `Map` that the keys are used in. [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) can support functions as keys, and I tried out using `menuItem.Page` as my key and it seems to work fine, but the types in the code clearly indicate `string | number` as the type of the key.

For now my conclusion is that types other than `string | number` should be avoided since the source declares this as a restriction and that there may be reasons I am unaware of (possibly regarding future plans) that may make this restriction more important than it currently seems to be, but I'm still curious if there are stronger reasons to restrain the types used for keys.